# Hide particular div onload and then show div after click

Tags: html, click, jquery

I have two divs `div1` and `div2`. I want div2 to be automatically hidden but when i click on `preview` div then `div2` to be made visible and `div1` to hide. This is the code i tried but no luck :(

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div2").hide();
  $("#preview").click(function() {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
  });
});
</script>

<div id="div1">
This is preview Div1. This is preview Div1.
</div>

<div id="div2">
This is preview Div2 to show after div 1 hides.
</div>

<div id="preview" style="color:#999999; font-size:14px">
PREVIEW
</div>
```

Comment: $("#div2").show();  //$("#div2").hide();

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure to watch your selectors. You appear to have forgotten the `#` for `div2`. Additionally, you can toggle the visibility of many elements at once with `.toggle()`:

```
// Short-form of `document.ready`
$(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#preview").on("click", function(){
        $("#div1, #div2").toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dJg8N/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that selector notification ..and really for that toggle really i need to figure it on my own :( will approve your comment in 5min

Comment: @swapnesh It's just a matter of time. Before too long, this will all be second-nature to you ;) Keep visiting StackOverflow, and you'll find yourself learning something new every day.

Answer (score 7):

This is an easier way to do it. Hope this helps...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#preview").toggle(function() {
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
    });
});

<div id="div1">
This is preview Div1. This is preview Div1.
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none;">
This is preview Div2 to show after div 1 hides.
</div>

<div id="preview" style="color:#999999; font-size:14px">
PREVIEW
</div>
```

- If you want the div to be hidden on load, make the style ***display:none***
- Use *toggle* rather than *click* function.

*Links:*

#### JQuery Tutorials

- http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp (W3Schools)
- http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32 (Video Tutorials)
- http://andreehansson.se/the-basics-of-jquery/ (Basic Tutorial)

#### JQuery References

- http://api.jquery.com/
- http://oscarotero.com/jquery/

Comment: thx for he info :) im really trying to get hands on jquery ...do u have any link that help me to improve my jquery :)

Comment: @swapnesh 
I edited my initial post and added links. Personally, I feel the best way to learn jquery is to see it in action. I use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) for testing and use [http://api.jquery.com/](http://api.jquery.com/) &  [http://oscarotero.com/jquery/](http://oscarotero.com/jquery/) for references to events/methods/etc. I have made an example page for you on jsfiddle (feel free to use that as a template): [http://jsfiddle.net/83UdX/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/83UdX/3/). Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `#` hash character before id selectors, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div2").hide();

    $("#preview").click(function() {
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").show();
    });

});
```

---

[Learn More about jQuery ID Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div2').hide(0);
    $('#preview').on('click', function() {
        $('#div1').hide(300, function() { // first hide div1
            // then show div2
            $('#div2').show(300);
        });     
    });
});
```

You missed `#` before `div2`

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hjVyR/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The second time you're referring to div2, you're not using the # id selector.

There's no element named div2.

Answer (score 0):

At first if you want to hide div element with id = "abc" on load and then toggle between hide and show using a button with id = "btn" then,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#abc").hide(); 
  $("#btn").click(function() {
     $("#abc").toggle();
  });
});
```